# Error in console but displays in browser

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-forms, http-parameters

I have  a problem in my angular app that says ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined but the projects.name is displaying. How can i get rid of the error in the console.log. The data contains an object.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params 
      .subscribe((params: Params) => { 
      this.id = +params['id']; 
      this.projectsService = this.injector.get(ProjectsService);
      this.projectsService.getProject(this.id)
      .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.projects = data;
            console.log(data);

          },
          error => {
            alert("ERROR");
          })
      });  
}
```

Comment: `asdasdf?.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you directly used `projects.name` and `projects` is being retrieved by ajax. This code fails because it tries to `projects.name` binding on initial change detection run.

In such cases `Use Safe Navigation / Elvis` operator

```
{{projects?.name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use {{projects?.name}} or you should initialize your projects... best practice is to use the interface and the class for your projects.